# Convert a string to a function

Tags: javascript

Total newbie question.
how do i get the following code to work.

```
var f_str = "function test(msg) { alert(msg) }"
var f = eval(f_str)
f("hello")
```

The idea is to have the function test as a string, and be able to execute it as a function.
eval doesn't seem to work, and i have tried JSON.parse too, without luck..

Comment: I don't know your actual need but if you're using eval, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Add parentheses around `f_str`, so that it's interpreted as a function expression.

```
var f_str = "(function test(msg) { alert(msg) })";
var f = eval(f_str);
f("hello");
```

In your current code, the code is interpreted as a function declaration. You can see this by printing / using the value of `test`:

```
var f_str = "function test(msg) { alert(msg) }";
var f = eval(f_str);//^^^^
test("hello");   // <--
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a bad idea; if you want to execute dynamic JavaScript, you can use a snippet like this:

```
  (function() {
    var code = document.createElement('script');
    code.type = 'text/javascript';
    code.async = true;
    code.src = '/path/to/script';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(code, s);
  }());
```

Or use `jQuery.getScript()`:

```
$.getScript('/path/to/script');
```